# need to retrieve windows logged in user in Jboss

Tags: iis, single-sign-on, jboss7.x

My application was running Jboss 4.2.3 GA and i enabled the tomcatauthentication in server.xml. I also enabled integrated windows authentication on IIS. By doing these steps, i was able to retrieve the logged in user by request.getRemoteUser().

Now application is upgraded to Jboss 7 and there is no tomcatauthentication flag available. Is there any way to extract the username in the application?

Comment: Did you see the answer below? Was it helpful?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you connect IIS and JBoss using AJP Connector.
Ensure you set the `tomcatAuthentication="false"` attribute on the AJP  element, otherwise you will not get `REMOTE_USER`. See Tomcat's AJP Connector documentation for more details: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/ajp.html